# Vuejs - Como adicionar testes e2e/unitário depois de não incluir eles inicialmente na criação do projeto webpack?

Tags: vue.js, testes-de-unidade, vue.js-2, nightwatch, e2e

Possuo um projeto que foi iniciado com o webpack do vuetify (vue init vuetifyjs/webpack). No momento que foi criado o projeto, não foi selecionado a opção de testes e2e/unitários. Porém agora há a necessidade de realizar os testes.

Verifiquei a instalação manual do nightwatch primeiramente, e instalei todas as dependências necessárias via npm, como, por exemplo:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
npm i -D babel-register chromedriver cross-spawn nightwatch selenium-server
```

Inseri no script também, para que possa ser executado:

```
"e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
"test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e"`
```

Porém, ocorre erros, mediante ao arquivo `webpack.dev.conf.js`. Aparece que `devConfigPromise.then(devConfig => { TypeError: devConfigPromise.then is not a function`, e realmente não é, pois para verificar criei um outro projeto hoje do zero e o arquivo `webpack.dev.conf.js` está extremamente diferente do meu, bem como ele possui a exportação de uma `Promise`, entre outras novas dependências, o qual é necessária para resolver este erro do `devConfigPromise` utilizar o `.then`.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou em alguma situação como essa, e sabe de alguma solução relativamente fácil para este caso, pois tentei "integrar" o `webpack.dev.conf.js` do novo projeto no meu antigo, porém ocorre diversos problemas, e cheguei em um ponto que não sei mais como resolver.

Tentei procurar, mas não encontrei nada sobre isto até o momento, o que ao meu ver é estranho, pois senão acaba ficando assim: Ou você inicia o projeto com testes, ou cria outro.

Se ajudar, posso postar o código dos arquivos de configuração, no caso deste projeto existe três para o desenvolvimento, o `webpack.dev.conf.js`, o `dev-client.js` e o `dev-server.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta no stackoverflow NA que foi respondida dois dias atrás no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361246/vue-how-do-you-add-e2e-tests-after-not-including-them-in-initial-webpack-templa/49882074#49882074

Brevemente explicando a solução para aqueles que estiverem com o mesmo problema, primeiramente você deve encontrar o boilerplate (ou template) que corresponde à versão que o seu projeto está. Por sorte, no meu caso estava na versão 1.1.0 e o template que consta na resposta é a mesma.

Caso não seja, verifique a versão do boilerplate que você está utilizando e procure iniciar (ou algum projeto iniciado) com a opção de testes e2e. Em seguida, copie toda a pasta `test` para o seu projeto. Feito isso, adicione `e2e` e `test` no script como consta na resposta e instale as dependências `chromedriver e`selenium-server`(talvez tenha que instalar a`webpack-dev-server`) como modo desenvolvimento, no caso do npm seria com a flag`--save-dev`.

Ainda não cheguei a realizar os testes à fundo, mas aparentemente resolveu, pelo menos no caso do `e2e` com `nightwatch`.